# iOS MDM : Can any MDM SDK send MDM command without Internet?

Tags: ios, mdm

iOS MDM : Can any MDM SDK send MDM command without Internet ?

In offline situation (while iPhone do not have internet connectivity - like Airplane Mode)  if need to generate mdm command to change the profile (change the restrictions), is it possible ?

Comment: How would the MDM payload get to the device if it isn't connected to a network?

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not support this as the mdm daemon only communicates over https.

Android supports partial configuration of settings via a local app (especially via the old Admin profile which is now deprecated).